# Программа падает с ошибкой Can not load 7-zip library

Tags: c#, 7z

Программа падает с ошибкой

> SevenZip.SevenZipLibraryException   HResult=0x80131500
>   Сообщение = Can not load 7-zip library or internal COM error! Message: failed to
>   load library.   Источник = SevenZipSharp
>
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку
>   "SevenZipSharp, Version=0.64.3890.29348, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=20de82c62b055c88" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не
>   удается найти указанный файл."

```
var currentDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
SevenZipCompressor.SetLibraryPath(currentDir + @"\"  + @"Resources\7z.dll");
var cmpr = new SevenZipCompressor();
cmpr.CompressFiles(archiveName, fileNames);
```

При этом когда программа запускается в из под Visual Studio то всё работает нормально. А при обычном запуске падает.

Comment: Вам стоит между первой и второй строками добавить вывод в лог или на экран значение выражения `currentDir + @"\"  + @"Resources\7z.dll"` и проверить, действительно ли по этому пути лежит 7z.dll

Comment: да и даже работает когда запускается в VS . Но когда запускается exe то не работает